# Binding Entities to a Windows DataGridView

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, sorting, datagridview

I have an EF source that I'm binding to a DataGridView. The binding is happening programatically. However, the sorting is not working.

So I decided to mess with some code and create an Extension Method, but it seems like its still not working.

```
public static class BindingListEntityExtension
{
    public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        BindingList<T> rtn = new BindingList<T>();

        foreach (T obj in entities)
        {
            rtn.Add(obj);
        }

        return rtn;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately `BindingList<T>` is a very basic implementation of `IBindingList`, and doesn't support sorting... However you could inherit from it and provide your own sorting logic. You could also take a look at the `SortableBindingList<T>` mentioned by Ecyrb

Comment: So I've got to find a type that does implement sorting. Hmmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran across this [article](http://www.timvw.be/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/) for a `SortableBindingList<T>`.  Works great.  You may be able to figure out how to get your extension method working by checking out the source.

Answer (score 1):

The data binding relies on the `IBindingList` interface for filtering and sorting, and this interface is not implemented by your EF source. To enable sorting this data source, you would have to create a wrapper that implements `IBindingList`.