# Extending IEnumerable to Return BindingList

Tags: entity-framework, data-binding, sorting, extension-methods

In a previous question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394816/binding-entities-to-a-windows-datagridview), I had run into an issue with returning an EF query to the DataGridView. Of course I'd run into an issue. However, I added an extension method that still has me baffled since it isn't working. It seems like it should, but for some reason it's not.

```
public static class BindingListEntityExtension
{
    public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        BindingList<T> rtn = new BindingList<T>();

        foreach (T obj in entities)
        {
            rtn.Add(obj);
        }

        return rtn;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what's going on? My implementation is like so:

```
MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
tempDataGridView.DataSource = context.Employees.ToBindingList();
```

Comment: What is not working?  Is it the sorting that you mentioned in your previous question?  If so, I posted an answer to that question that may help.

Comment: I second that, what is actually failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. As Ecyrb had suggested in a previous post, the BindingList does not sort. I did use the [suggested site/](http://www.timvw.be/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/) to get my list to sort. Thanks guys! My extension does work now.

Comment: Link is broken. As per stackoverflow policy, it is suggested to always answer the question with the action, backup by the link to an answer. It is not recommend to only use a link to an answer without the answer itself.