# Windows Forms: Refresh Bindings works only for added items not for updated ones

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, binding

I want to create an undo button:

```
private void btn_Undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_storesBS.DataSource = _storeRepository.GetAll();
    StoresBindingNavigator.BindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

This works well, when I add an item and then push the undo button.

But if I edit an item by changing a textbox value and push the undo button the textbox (in detail view) and the value in the grid view (overview) is not reseted.

The grid view and the textbox are both connected to the binding source (`m_storesBS`)

**Edit:**

I tried to change the list type of the GetAll method with no succes:

```
public virtual BindingList<T> GetAll()
{
    return _objectSet.ToBindingList();
}
```

Comment: What kind is your binding source of?

Comment: IEnumerable of a complex type

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `BindingList<YourType>` to bind the data to your control. Changes will then be reflected without any additional work.

Comment: Like that `m_storesBX.DataSource = new BindingList<YourType>(_storeRepository.GetAll());`

Comment: I'm now using a BindingList<T> but the error still exists. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396256/extending-ienumerable-to-return-bindinglist

Comment: I didn_t knew, that you were using EntityFramework. (You didn't mention that in your question nor tags). Here is a link to MSDN how to bind EntityFramework to GridView and other controls. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738469.aspx)

Comment: Well using ObjectQuery in my repository will expose EntityFramework details. Furthermore my UI is coupled to EF. Do you know a manual approach?

Comment: The only option I know is to build a business layer between your EntityFramework and the UI. The busines layer can populate a BindingList and has to manage the update of changes between EntityFramework and that BindingList. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that EF was caching my whole list (`_storeRepository.GetAll();`).

I now use a method on my repository called Refresh.

```
public void Refresh(T entity, bool storeWins = true)
{
    _objectContext.Refresh(
       storeWins ? RefreshMode.StoreWins : RefreshMode.ClientWins, entity);
}
```

Undo button:

```
private void btn_Undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var store = GetCurrentStore();
    _storeRepository.Refresh(store);
    StoresBindingNavigator.BindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

With this I enforce EF to call to the database.